# Как автоматизировать docker-compose на сервере?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

Сейчас я имею два контейнера которые загружаю на гит хаб и докерхаб автоматом их подтягивает/билдит и уже на сервере я делаю докер пул и запускаю. 
Так же локально я запускал через docker-compose , но как правильно загружать его на сервер и запускать и желательно это все автоматизировать? 
Как в таком случае в docker-compose отслеживать что если один контейнер упал и например не перезапустился?
Для меня пока оверхед использовать сварм или к8б.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> Как в таком случае в docker-compose отслеживать что если один контейнер упал

Добавить [`healthcheck`](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/06dd5917c1900d7f565a2dfc4a95cef0c58e39e4/docker-compose.swarm.yml#L8)

> и например не перезапустился?

Добавить `restart: always` для docker-compose или `restart_policy` для [swarm](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/06dd5917c1900d7f565a2dfc4a95cef0c58e39e4/docker-compose.swarm.yml#L19)

> Так же локально я запускал через docker-compose, но как правильно загружать его на сервер и запускать и желательно это все автоматизировать?

- [build & push](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/ansible/roles/build/tasks/main.yml)
- [pull & deploy](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/ansible/roles/deploy/tasks/main.yml)

*На сервер попадает только стек файл, который удаляется после деплоя, и загружаются images из registry.*

Использовал docker-compose + ansible + [bash (для получения одного stack файла)](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/deploy).

Пример: [CI & CD](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)

И [результаты](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/runs/623239403?check_suite_focus=true)

> Для меня пока оверхед использовать сварм или к8б

Советую использовать **swarm**, даже для **одного сервера** (staging / production).

**Overhead** будет писать свою обвязку + тестирование + поддержка.

Comment: Все равно не доходит следующий момент — приложение в контейнер пулится с установленными зависимостями ? Или процесс развертывания все же происходит на продакшене? (Под развертыванием я имею в виду установка зависимостей, возможная обработка статики и т.д и т.п.) Либо процесс развёртывания заключается в вашем случае на скачивание нового image и запуск контейнера, в котором приложение полностью собрано ?

Comment: > на скачивание нового image и запуск контейнера, в котором приложение полностью собрано

Да, именно так, в идеале должно быть. Все обработку желательно вести на этапе build, используя multi-stage syntax (для статики на пример).

Comment: На production / staging ничего не делаем, кроме скачивания images и поднятия стека. Таким образом появляется скрипты доставки любого докеризированного стека приложения, и не важно насколько сложный build внутри.

Comment: Спасибо что поделились опытом.